# How to use condition in EventTrigger in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two questions.

**Q1:** How can I use conditions in an `EventTrigger`?

In the following code you can see two `EventTriggers` for `ListBoxItem`. As you can see, This `EventTriggers` is for `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateItemDirect">
            ...
            ...
            ...
         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="borderItem" RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ParallelTimeline>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                                <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.1" Value="0,40,0,0" />
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </ParallelTimeline>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="borderItem" RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ParallelTimeline>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,40,0,0" />
                                <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.1" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </ParallelTimeline>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Q2:** In the server side code (C# Code), I've defined a public static bool variable and my condition is that when the variable was equal to `True`, `EventTrigger` do their work. My goal is to give the option to the users to enable or disable animations in `EventTrigger`s.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1 :** Conditions cannot be used in the XAML but in your code.

**Q2 :** Why is your `bool` variable declared as `static` ?

If you want to give the users a possibility to disable or enable something, may be you could use a checkbox and bind it to your `bool` variable.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, an `EventTrigger` in XAML simply hooks an event to an animation. Your requirements cannot be accomplished with XAML alone. One way that you could implement your requirements would be to attach an event handler to the events in XAML and then do the conditional part in the event handler.

First, you'll need to define your `Storyboard`s in some `Resources` section so that you can access them from the event handler. Then you can check the value of your `bool` variable and programmatically start the `Storyboard` from there if it is `true`.

In `Resources`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="YourStoryboard" ... />
</Window.Resources>
```

In XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateItemDirect">
            ...
         <Border Name="borderItem" DataContext="{Binding}" 
             MouseEnter="MainWindow_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MainWindow_MouseLeave" ... />
            ...
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In the event handler:

```
private void MainWindow_MouseEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender.DataContext).YourBoolVariable)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard = (Storyboard)FindResource("YourStoryboard");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard , YourControl);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

In order to deal with multiple animations individually, you can add the `YourBoolVariable` into your data item class (so that you have one for each animation). Then in the `DataTemplate`, you can set the `DataContext` of the `Border` to the data bound item and then retrieve it in the event handlers. The code example has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: Unfortunately, Handler doesn't recognized in EventTrigger! :(

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was thinking about the [`EventSetter` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter(v=vs.110).aspx)... I've corrected the error.

Comment: I have another problem. I think if we do this, we will have a new problem. Because I've defined StoryBoards for every single of ListBoxItems. :(

Comment: I still have this problem. is there any solution to solve this problem? tnx